# No HDMI sound on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi

I'm very new to Ubuntu/Linux.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop (nVidia gpu) in dual boot, and, with some help from Google, I'm almost ready to go.

The only thing that I can't figure out is how to play sound trough my HDMI connected to my TV. Speakers of the laptop are ok, in the sound settings I can see -hdmi -digital -speaker outputs. The top 2 won't play sound so I Googled around, found a bunch of things to try but the only thing successful so far was to erase all the drivers from the audio settings and they stayed gone. So finally I re-installed from scratch but still no sound trough HDMI. I tried reinstalling several times, but it didn't work. How can I play sound on my TV connected with HDMI?

I will be glad to give more info if needed cuz this is driving me crazy,
thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I Installed alsa control, un-mute everything and sound was ok.

```
sudo apt-get install alsamixergui
```